# Arquillian test with real EAR from build on JBoss 7.1

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x, jboss-arquillian

I want to test an Java EE application with Arquillian. A simple setup is working to put some test classes onto the server managed by Arquillian to test them.

Now, I want to use a EAR file which was build during the build process. With

```
@Deployment
public static EnterpriseArchive createDeployment() {
    File earFile = ...
    EnterpriseArchive archive = ShrinkWrap.createFromZipFile(EnterpriseArchive.class, earFile);
    return archive;
}
```

I am able to put the EAR via Arquillian to JBoss. I see the deployment and there are no errors during deployment. Only Arquillian returns with an error that it can not find the test class, which is obviously ok.

Now is the question where to put the test class to. I can put the test class into the test.war put into the EAR by Arquillian, but I get an ArquillianServletRunner not found exception. When I put the test classes into JAR files as module or library the test classes are not found when put as module or the injects do not work when put as libraries due to dependency issues.

Where to I have to put the test classes to???

My arquillian.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<arquillian xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian/arquillian_1_0.xsd">

   <defaultProtocol type="Servlet 3.0" />

    <container qualifier="jboss7" default="true">
        <configuration>
            <property name="jbossHome">${cargo.dir}/jboss-as-dist-7.1.1.Final/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final</property>
        </configuration>
    </container>

    <engine>
        <property name="deploymentExportPath">target/deployments</property>
    </engine>

</arquillian>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can run your test class on the client side using @Deployment(testable = false), but this has the downside that you cannot use the persistence extention (and maybe others) at the moment.

My example code:

```
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class PersonWebServiceIT {

    private PersonWebService service;

    @Deployment(testable = false)
    public static Archive<?> createDeployment() {
        return ShrinkWrap
                .create(ZipImporter.class, "test.war")
                .importFrom(
                        new File("simple-webservice-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war"))
                .as(WebArchive.class);
    }

    @Test
    public void testFindPersons(@ArquillianResource URL deploymentUrl) {
        ....
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Putting the test classes to the war inside the ear did work for me

```
WebArchive war = ear.getAsType(WebArchive.class, "/mywarname.war");
war.addClass(MyTestClass.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

When I am dealing with existing EAR, I prefer to separate the WAR that runs the tests, from the actual tests that I put in special JAR along with other testing EJBs. I have posted an example how do I do it with the necessary `application.xml` manipulation under similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17036383/1667977