# How to add test classes to an imported ear file and run server side with arquillian?

Tags: jboss-arquillian

I want to create integration tests using arquillian. As deployment i want to use the ear that is also used to deploy in production.

So this is my deployment:

```
@Deployment(testable = true)
public static Archive<?> createDeployment() {
    return ShrinkWrap
            .create(ZipImporter.class, "test.ear")
            .importFrom(new File("simple-webservice-ear-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear"))
            .as(EnterpriseArchive.class);
}
```

When i run my test class I get a java.lang.ClassNotFoundException because the test class is not found. I know I can set testable=false on the deployment but then the persistence extension doesn't work: see [arquillian persistence extension doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14694738/arquillian-persistence-extention-doesnt-work).

How can i solve this problem?
Is there a way to add my test class to the deployment? Or should i create my deployment in another way?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the way provided by Cheesus. When I am dealing with existing EAR, I prefer to separate the WAR that runs the tests, from the actual tests that I put in special JAR along with other testing EJBs. My deployment looks like this:

```
@Deployment
public static EnterpriseArchive createDeployment() {

    String path = System.getProperty(EAR_PATH);
    File f = new File(path);
    EnterpriseArchive ear = ShrinkWrap.createFromZipFile(EnterpriseArchive.class, f);

    final JavaArchive foobarEjb = ShrinkWrap.create(JavaArchive.class, "foobarEjb.jar");

    foobarEjb.addClasses(
                    MyTest1.class, 
                    MyTest2.class);
    ear.addAsModule(foobarEjb);


    final WebArchive war = ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class, "test.war")
            .addAsWebInfResource("WEB-INF/web.xml")
            .addAsWebResource("index.xhtml");

    ear.addAsModule(Testable.archiveToTest(war));

    modifyApplicationXML(ear);
    modifyJBossDeploymentStructure(ear);


    return ear;
}
```

Notice the methods to modify the `application.xml` and `jboss-deployment-structure.xml`. I need these to propertly initialize the JAR as an EjbModule inside the EAR.

Example how do I change `application.xml`:

```
private static void modifyApplicationXML(EnterpriseArchive ear) {
    Node node = ear.get("META-INF/application.xml");

    DescriptorImporter<ApplicationDescriptor> importer =  Descriptors.importAs(ApplicationDescriptor.class, "test");
    ApplicationDescriptor desc = importer.fromStream(node.getAsset().openStream());

    String xml = desc.exportAsString();

    // remove lib definition
    xml = xml.replaceAll("<library-directory>.*<\\/library-directory>", "");

    desc = (ApplicationDescriptor) importer.fromString(xml);
    // append foobar test ejbs
    desc.ejbModule("foobarEjb.jar");
    // append test war
    desc.webModule("test.war", "/test");
    // append lib definition
    desc.libraryDirectory("lib/");

    Asset asset = new StringAsset(desc.exportAsString());

    ear.delete(node.getPath());
    ear.setApplicationXML(asset);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can manually add the test class to the war inside the ear like

```
WebArchive war = ear.getAsType(WebArchive.class, "/mywarname.war");
war.addClass(MyTestClass.class);
```